# Using variable in Selenium IDE for a click on a link

Tags: variables, selenium, ide, click, selenium-ide

I want to do the same set of operations on different pages that are called by a click on a target "link=1" for page 1, then "link=2" for page 2... Hence, I want to automate the clicking on 1, then 2, etc.

How should I proceed? I was considering using label and goto label (Flow Control plug-in for Firefox) with a variable that would increase each time. However I do not know how to increment a variable in Selenium IDE and above all how to use a variable in the field target for the click (I tried link=${variablename} which does not work).

I'm a beginner with not much programming experience, mainly using the capture/recording tool of Selenium IDE and modifying the obtained results, so a simple solution -even not the optimal one- would be appreciate. Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example to increment:

```
<tr>
<td>store</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>counter</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>${counter}+1</td>
<td>counter</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>${counter}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

The variable counter should remain in scope through all tests in the suite.

```
store     | 1            | counter
storeEval | ${counter}+1 | counter
echo      | ${counter}   |
```

Comment: Thanks ! It was exactly what I needed. After using your incrementation (with a syntax I could never have guessed !!), link=${variablename} does work.

Comment: Great. Feel free to accept the answer then. Thanks.